# tangent cone and simplex

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, convex-optimization, polytopes

Let $X \subset \mathbb R^d$ be a simplex and $x \notin X$

> Prove that there exists a unique face $F \subseteq X $  with minimal dimension $\dim(F)=\dim(aff(F))$ such that $x \in K_F$ where $K_F:=\{x+\lambda(y-x):\lambda \ge 0 \;x\in F,y\in X \}$ denotes the tangent cone of $F$

Note: $\mathrm{aff}(F)$ is supposed to be the affine hull.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What are your approaches? Also where does the "tangent cone" from the title appear in the question?

Comment: @M.Winter The tangent cone  in the title is $K_F$. At least that's my definition of  a tangent cone given a face $F$ of $X$

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to prove this by contradiction.

Let $F_1\neq F_2$ be two faces of $X$ that satisfy your constraints. Because $x\in K_{F_i}$, there are $p_i\in F_i$ and $q_i\in X$ such that $x$ belongs to the ray from $p_i$ through $q_i$. The properties of $p_i$ and $q_i$ are enough to derive a contradiction.

**Hint 1:**

> $X$ is a simplex and is thus convex, it must fully contain the segment between $q_1$ and $q_2$.

**Hint 2:**

> Because $x\notin X$, thus $x$ cannot be in the segment between $q_1$ and $q_2$. You can look at rays from $x$ and through points of that segment.

**Hint 3:**

> The existence of $p_1$ and $p_2$ guarantee that for each rays mentioned in hint 2, the last point of $X$ that is met by the ray is not in the segment $[q_1q_2]$, but somewhere further. Look at those points.

The three hints above should be more than enough to get you started. If you're still struggling, here are some more.

**Hint 4:**

> The points from hint 3 form a continuous path, let's call it $\gamma$. This path $\gamma$ entirely lies in the boundary of $X$. And each boundary point of $X$ belongs to some face of $X$ of dimension (strictly) less than $d$.

**Hint 5:**

> If you look at the points in $\gamma$, you obtain a sequence of faces of $X$ that starts from $F_1$ and ends with $F_2$. Because you go from one face to another face of the same dimension, at some point $\gamma$ must cross the boundary of $F_1$ and $F_2$. What property do those boundary points (of $F_1$/$F_2$) have?

The last hint is one step away from the conclusion.

**Hint 6:**

> Let $p$ be one of the points mentioned in hint 5. Point $p$ must belong to another face, $F_3$, whose dimension is (strictly) less than those of $F_1/F_2$. And it also belongs to $\gamma$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I just have one question. While this shows the uniqueness but what about existence ? I mean why does $x \in K_F$ for some face $F$ of $X$ ?

Comment: @XPenguen $X$ is the (unique) $d$-dimensional face of $X$, and $F_X=\mathbb R^d$. If you exclude $X$ as a face, the result is false.

Comment: Now I feel stupid :P Thanks for taking your time. I appreciate it